# the currentTime() method of the videojs plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I am using  the Videojs plugin as a video player; and I want when I restart the player for the second time; to start playing the video from the position where I was before leaving the player.

```
<div id="playerDiv">
      <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"  controls preload="none">
            <source src="http://xxxxxx/stepupallin_en_fr_ts.mpg"  type='video/mpg' id="videosrc" />
      </video>
 </div>
```

to play the video i used:

```
$('#playerDiv').append('<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"  controls preload="none" ><source src="http://xxxx/stepupallin_en_fr_ts.mpg" type="video/mpg"></video>');
    player = videojs("my_video_1"); 
    player.play();
```

to leave the player I used:
      whereYouAt = player.currentTime();//to get the position of the video befor 
                                         //leave it 
       var currentTime = localStorage.currentTime;
       localStorage.currentTime = whereYouAt;
        player.dispose();

when I play the video for the seconde time:

```
player.currentTime(localStorage.currentTime);
```

but i don't know why it doesn't work

I also tried to use offset but it doesn't work:

```
player.offset({
    start: localStorage.currentTime,
    end: localStorage.duration,
    restart_beginning: false 
});
```

all what i want is to play videojs from a given time

Answer (score 1):

`player.currentTime(localStorage.currentTime);`  cant work because values in localStorage are stored as string. Use `player.currentTime(parseFloat(localStorage.currentTime));` instead.